# rotating rectangle around a point

Tags: java, android, mobile, game-physics

I have a circle in the center of a rectangle. When I move my finger the rectangle should rotate. The rectangle center is the circle center. I've tried for a week and I can only get the top left and bottom right to change using an identity matrix to setrotate and even then it just stretches and doesn't really rotate. the rectangle wont change size just rotate. the new rectangle should keep its new points for detecting collision. anyone have any idea what is wrong?

```
mat = new matrix;

set rectangle;

rotate canvas;

mat.setRotate;

mat.mapRect(rectangle);
```

set rectangle again for transformed points;

sorry for the psudeocode I'm on my phone the internet is broke while att fixes it.

Comment: You might want to wait until you can post code... pseudo code only helps illustrate logic, but your problem is much more specific.